# How to remove the word "copy" when you copy & paste a file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When copy a file ".env", I hope to got a duplicated file named ".env 1" not ".env copy"

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behavior by setting the `explorer.incrementalNaming` to `smart`.

To do that, do the following:

1. cmd+,
2. search for: `explorer.incrementalNaming`
3. Change the setting to `smart`.

Otherwise, if you don't want to change the setting, you can just constantly change the filename after copy is complete. The fastest and most efficient way I found is through the following keyboard commands:

Select file in Explorer

1. ctrl+c (or cmd+c if you're on a mac)
2. ctrl+v (or cmd+v)
3. <enter>
4. right arrow once
5. backspace 5 times
6. then put in 1.